# Any clues for using a mysql installation on a bitlocked W10 drive, from Linux OS on dual boot?

Tags: permissions, windows, mysql, ownership

Booting to Linux Mint 20, I just installed a LAMP stack on this machine, accepting all default choices. But I already have all my databases on a Windows 10 bitlocked partition (now unlocked and accessible in Linux).

On the subject of moving the location of mysql's data files in Linux I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398493/595305)... which looked logical (NB the comment by Edenshaw applied: "I could not find the file my.cnf in your location, but instead here: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf").

My mysql installation on my bitlocked Windows drive is found under /media/bitlockermount-d/dbases/mariadb_data: under this you find ibdata1, ib_logfile[n], etc. Yes, it is a MariaDB installation.

After following the instructions of the linked answer, I got

```
root@M17A:/var/lib/mysql# service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

And then

```
root@M17A:/var/lib/mysql# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-01-02 13:23:39 GMT; 1min 19s ago
    Process: 335723 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 335731 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 335731 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied) ********** AHA... **********
```

This is logical, as I find that file ownership under /media/bitlockermount-d/dbases/mariadb_data has NOT CHANGED: it is still root:root, when it should have been changed to mysql:mysql by the following commands:

```
root@M17A:/var/lib/mysql# chown --reference=/var/lib/mysql /media/bitlockermount-d/dbases/mariadb_data
root@M17A:/var/lib/mysql# chmod --reference=/var/lib/mysql /media/bitlockermount-d/dbases/mariadb_data
```

... this is no doubt one reason at least why things failed. However, it is a bit puzzling because the permissions of **all** the files under ...dbases/mariadb_data is 777 (or said to be). So why can't mysql do what it wants with those files? Is it maybe explicitly checking ***ownership*** as part of its startup process?

I tried to find the formatting of the bitlock-unlocked partition. I couldn't manage to do so, but assume that it is ntfs or something non-Linuxy of that kind, thus explaining the failure to change ownership.

So the question: any way of getting round this? Is there any way I can tell mysql to somehow "run as root" or "ignore ownership problems" for example?

Comment: If you want to share a mysql database between windows and linux, don't do it this way.  You are asking for endless troubles.  Windows and Linux file permissions and ownership are completely different.   Instead: beg, buy, or scavenge the parts to build a small linux server (anything less than 10 or 20 years old should be good enough, except for the drive(s), they should be as new as possible).  Install mysql or mariadb and whatever other shared services you need on it (e.g. your LAMP stack, samba, nfs).  Configure both windows & linux on your dual-boot machine to use it as their mysql server.

Comment: a raspberry pi or similar would work well too.   or an old laptop (disable suspend or shutdown when lid is closed).

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking of a partition on this one machine formatted ext3 or ext4, solely for the purpose of housing the mysql files. I have a vague recollection I may have managed this in the past, and that W10 was in fact able to use it OK. Now, where might I have documented all that?

Comment: That might work, if building your own mysql server is impossible or impractical. I think there's an ext4 driver for windows. I've never used it so I have no idea how good it is, or what limitations it might have.   I'm not even sure if mysql on windows and mysql on linux use exactly the same on-disk file format - I'd test that first by copying or rsyncing the mysql directory back and forth a few times, and adding/deleting/updating records on both.   Make a backup before doing that, in case it doesn't work properly and corrupts your database.

Comment: I've been using this single database (MariaDB) on an ext4 partition devoted solely to the dbase files for about 9 months now without any problems: easily accessible, and manipulable, from both Linux and W10. I documented everything I did and there was indeed some wrestling with the dog's breakfast known as Windows ownership/permissions at the beginning. But it wasn't too difficult to overcome. I do an automated dbase dump backup (combined with restic) every 10 minutes whenever any of my dbase data changes.